# momentjs get date by providing week and weekday

Tags: momentjs

I there a way I can get a date through week and weekday?

so far I have for example:

> var week_number= 42, weekday = 4;

I have read most of the docs and searches in google and found nothing regarding this.

NOTE: To keep my code standard I would like to use momentjs

UPDATE: I am able to get the date through the week but what about the real date through weekday number?

```
var week_date    = moment().week(week_number),
    weekday_date = ????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
moment().week(42).weekday(4).startOf('day')
```

Though you should consider whether you should use `week` or `isoWeek`, and you should also consider whether to use `weekday`, `day`, or `isoWeekday`.

All of these functions, and the differences between them are in [the moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs).